# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration, spring-ws

I am writing a web application with Spring Framework 4.0.6 and I have to schedule a small routine to run everyday at the same time. I am trying it by using the @Scheduled annotation and adding the   tag in my dispatcher-servlet.xml , but I get a SAXParseException when the application starts. My xml file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/task/spring-task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackage" />
    <sws:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <task:annotation-driven />
```

The error i am getting is below:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 37 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.
    xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven
    '.
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Thanks In advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look where is a mistake:

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/task/spring-task"
```

So, you try to use a namespace as `spring-task` meanwhile it's location is:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
```

The namespace must be exactly as it is declared in the location.